# Prove pairs of combinations by a better approach.

Tags: combinatorics

Below is stated solved exercise 1.2.5 in book by: CHEN CHUAN-CHONG, KOH KHEE- MENG, titled : Principles and Techniques in combinatorics.

Let $S$ be the set of natural numbers whose digits are chosen from $\{1,3,5,7\}$ such that no digits are repeated. Find
(i) $|S|$;
(ii) $\sum_{n\in S}n$.

We divide $S$ into $4$ disjoint subsets consisting of:
(1) $1$-digit numbers: $1,3,5,7$;
(2) $2$-digit numbers: $13,15,...$;
(3) $3$-digit numbers: $135,137,...$;
(4) $4$-digit numbers: $1357,1375,...$;

and find $|S|$ by applying AP  (Addition Principle). Thus for $i = 1,2,3,4,\cdots$,  let $S_i$ denote the set of $i$-digit natural numbers formed by $1,3,5,7$ with no repetition. Then $S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4$ and by (AP),  
$|S| = \sum_{i=1}^{4}|S_i| = P_1^4 + P_2^4 + P_3^4+ P_4^4$  
$= 4+12 + 24 + 24 = 64$.

(ii)
There is a shortcut to compute the sum $\alpha= \sum (n | n \in S)$. Observe that the $4$ numbers in $S_1$ can be paired off as ${1,7}$ and ${3,5}$ so that the sum of the two numbers in each pair is equal to $8$ and the $12$ numbers in $S_2$ can be paired off as $\{13,75\}, \{15,73\}, \{17,71\}, \{35,53\}, \cdots $ so that the sum of the two numbers in each pair is $88$. Likewise, the $24$ numbers in $S_3$ and the $24$ numbers in $S_4$ can be paired off so that the sum of the two numbers in each pair is equal to $888$ and $8888$ respectively. Thus, 
$\alpha = 8\times \frac 42 +   88\times \frac {12}2  + $$
 888\times\frac{24}2 + 8888\times\frac{24}2$$
=117856$.

Doubts in (ii):

Is there a way to prove that the pairing are always there?

To take an example, by (i) there are only $12$ pairs from four digits for $S_2$ as stated below:

$(1,3), (3,1), (5,7), (7,5), (1,5), (5,1), (5,3), (3,5), (7,3), (3,7), 
(1,7), (7,1)$

These can be paired as:
$(1,3), (7,5)$ 
$(5,7), (3,1)$ 
$(1,7), (7,1)$ 
$(1,5), (7,3)$ 
$(3,7), (5,1)$ 
$(5,3), (3,5)$

But, it gets difficult to show pairing of enumerated cases for $S_3$, or $S_4$.

For $S_3$, by (i) there are $24$ pairs from four digits as stated below:

$(1,3,5), (1,5,3), (1,5,7), (1,7,5),(1,3,7), (1,7,3)$
$ 
(3,5,1), (3,1,5), (3,5,7), (3,7,5), (3,1,7), (3,7,1)$
$
(5,1,7), (5,7,1), (5,3,7), (5,7,3), (5,3,1), (5,1,3)$
$
(7,3,1), (7,1,3), (7,5,3), (7,3,5),(7,5,1), (7,1,5)$

These can be paired as:
$(1,3,5), (7,5,3)$ 
But, it is difficult to show all $12$ pairings.

It would be even more difficult to show all the pairs in $S_4$.

So, is there a better (theoretical) way to show that all such pairings exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d_1d_2\ldots d_n$ be any string of digits from the set $\{1,3,5,7\}$. For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $\bar d_k=8-d_k$. Then $\bar d_1\bar d_2\ldots\bar d_n$ is also a string of digits from the set $\{1,3,5,7\}$, and

$$d_1d_2\ldots d_n+\bar d_1\bar d_2\ldots\bar d_n=\underbrace{88\ldots 8}_n\,.$$

Note that if $d_i\ne d_j$, then $\bar d_i\ne\bar d_j$, so if the first string has no repeated digits, the new string also has no repeated digits. (Of course this can happen only if $n\le 4$.) Moreover, if we apply the same process to $\bar d_1\bar d_2\ldots\bar d_n$, we get back the original string $d_1d_2\ldots d_n$, so this is a genuine pairing of all of the strings of length $n$ that have no repeated digits; it tells you immediately, for instance, that the string paired with $3175$ is $5713$.

Comment: Thanks, can we extend this to higher set of digits from which to form string? It seems that need even number of digits in set, else pairing is not possible. Say, $\{1,2,3,7,8,9\}$, then would find sum to $10$. So, can we state condition to extend the set and to choose digits according to the set size?

Comment: @jiten: You can do it whenever the digits themselves can be paired up so that each pair has the same sum. This is possible with $\{1,2,3,7,8,9\}$, for instance, with sum $10$, and it would also be possible with $\{2,4,7,8\}$, again with sum $10$. With $\{1,2,3,4\}$ you could do with sum $5$.